# Simple javascript detect user's device

Tags: javascript, iphone

I want to add javascript into my template to detect that every time users view my websites with what kind of device (Smartphone, tablet or PC).

Currently, I try to do it with javascript, here it is:

```
var smartPhone = "smartphone";
var Ipod = "ipod";

var userDevice = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

function DetectPhone()
{
   if (userDevice.search(smartPhone) > -1)
      return true;
   else
      windows.location = "/pageforphone.aspx";
}

function DetectIpod()
{
   if (userDevice.search(Ipod) > -1)
      return true;
   else
      windows.location = "/pageforpod.aspx";
}
```

Did I write the codes right? Honestly, no iPhone...

Of course, if these were completed with Php or Asp.net would be better, but is it true that people always turn the javascript off on their palm devices?
Also, i think iphone or ipod or any other tablets are quite similar, is it ok that i use same redev pages for those devices? Actually i am not very understanding what is the differences among them and what should i be aware when i redev my web pages.

Comment: Browser detection can get pretty involved pretty fast, but there are some pretty decent sniffing scripts floating around (e.g. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

Comment: Why do you want to know? If you are just collecting statistics, the server already has the information. If you are sniffing for functionalty, you are at a dead end. Test for functionality, not user agent string, which is completely unreliable and ever changing. There are **thousands** of them already, with new ones being added more or less daily. There are 2,400 or so listed on [useragent.org](http://www.user-agents.org/), and that is by no means exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of the question, that browser-sniffing is acceptable, is false. You should never engage in browser sniffing, simply because you cannot confidently accomplish what you set out to accomplish. User Agent Strings are not immutable, and are often times changed by plugins installed on the client machine, or by the client themselves (not uncommon, since bad programmers may lock them out of a site based on their UA-String).

Rather than asking *what* device the user is one, you should instead be asking *what functionality* is the device capable of. This brings you to *feature detection*, where you set out to do X, test to see if the user agent is capable of doing X, and then proceed to do or not do X. For instance:

```
if ( !!document.createElement("video").canPlayType ) {
  console.log( "HTML5 Video Supported" );
}
```

This is more reliable than trying to see if the user is on an iPhone, iPad, Windows Tablet, or HTML5 Enabled Browser. You can use tools like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to perform a lot of these tests for you - over 40 in fact.

Comment: Agree, modernizr is the way to go with detecting browser features

Answer (score 0):

There many mobile devices on the market + each device can have more than one browser installed. I would prefer using some library rather than funding "iPhone" in user agent string (I'm using Android phone with Opera browser myself)

For example:

- http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/
- http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/ - server side, has a large database of devices and features supported
- http://modernizr.com - client size JavaScript library, detects which HTML5 features available on browsers (e.g. geolocation API, video, Index DB, local storage, etc.)

Both of them are regularly updated with latest mobile devices released and provide you with information which features are supported on given device

Answer (score -1):

This is how I use javascript to detect iOS devices

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var isiPhone = ((agent.indexOf('iphone'))!=-1)

    if (((agent.indexOf('iphone'))!=-1) {
        document.location = "mobile.aspx?device=iphone";
    }

    if (((agent.indexOf('ipod'))!=-1) {
        document.location = "mobile.aspx?device=ipod";
    }

    if (((agent.indexOf('iPad'))!=-1) {
        document.location = "mobile.aspx?device=ipad";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that creating separate page for each device is a good idea from application maintenance perspective. (and not everyone is buying Apple products :-) ) Reminds me of same technique used 10 years ago with separate pages for IE and Netscape. You should decect browser features and screen size rather than hardlocking to specific device type or model

Comment: it's an example, you can even do **mobile.asp?device=iphone**, etc.

Comment: if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 4") != -1) { window.location="ienn4.htm";}

Does that code looks familiar to you? Are you going to rewrite your JavaScipt code when iNext is released?

Comment: if (((agent.indexOf('ipad'))!=-1) note that you are searching in a lowercase string ;)